# Java parsing UTF8

Tags: java, character-encoding, utf-8

I have the following issue with a UTF8 files structured as following:

> FIELD1§FIELD2§FIELD3§FIELD4

Looking at hexadecimal values of the file it uses `A7` to codify `§`. So according to this codify it should be UTF8, but it's strange because `A7` > `7F` so 1 byte shouldn't be enough to codify `§`.

So I tried using directly a `BufferedReader` with a specified charset:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input), utf8))
```

but when I try to tokenize the string with

```
SmartTokenizer st = new SmartTokenizer(toTokenize, "§")
```

(the `SmartTokenizer` is a modified version of the `StringTokenizer` that keeps empty tokens)

no splitting occurs, and if I try to print the string I obtain

> FIELD1?FIELD2?FIELD3?...

so `§` used in the file is different from the one specified as a the delimiter, and it's not able to print out it too.

So what's the problem here? Maybe the original file should use 2 bytes to store `§`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UTF-8 encoding of `§` is `0xC2 0xA7`.

If the file uses `A7` to represent `§`, then it's probably writtein in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (or another ISO-8859-* or their derivates).

Comment: Yes, I was looking into the wrong direction, after trying to convert between standards and so on.. I just told BufferedReader to read according to ISO-8859-1 charset.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at hexadecimal values of the file it uses A7 to codify §. So
>   according to this codify it should be UTF8

Uh, why? It's ISO8859-1 (or latin-1 or related one)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1